# Split a vector into 3 columns based on given intervals

Tags: r, vector, split

Very basic questio, but not sure how to start:

I have generated 200 random values:

```
SE <- runif(200, 0, 0.65)
```

Out of this i would like to create 3 columns: `se.sw`, `se.m` and `se.st` that contain values from intervals [0,0.05], ]0.05, 0.35] and ]0.35, 0.65] respectively.

**How can i acomplish this ?**

I have tried using a nested `ifelse` function, but it didnt work. This seems like an easy problem that i am spending too much time with...

Comment: need more information about this issue

Comment: @Gabri what kind of information?

Comment: See `?cut` and `?split`. feed the results of the first function to the second function.

Answer (score 0):

```
> SE.SW <- SE[SE >=0 & SE <= .05 ]
> SE.M <- SE[SE >.05 & SE <= .35 ]
> SE.ST <- SE[SE >.35 & SE <= .65 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `findInterval` and `split` in base R:

```
x <- findInterval(SE, c(0,0.05,0.35,0.65))
split(SE, x)

# $`1`
# [1] 0.04016108

# $`2`
# [1] 0.1725806 0.2418805 0.1310933

# $`3`
# [1] 0.3723547 0.5903351 0.5839533 0.6140389 0.4295186 0.4089241
```

---

OR using `cut` and `split`:

```
x <- cut(SE, breaks = c(0,0.05,0.35,0.65))
split(SE, x)

# $`(0,0.05]`
# [1] 0.04016108

# $`(0.05,0.35]`
# [1] 0.1725806 0.2418805 0.1310933

# $`(0.35,0.65]`
# [1] 0.3723547 0.5903351 0.5839533 0.6140389 0.4295186 0.4089241
```

**data**

```
set.seed(1)
SE <- runif(10, 0, 0.65)
```